# Join finished processes in multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am using a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) of `n` worker processes to map some function over a fully-defined iterable of size `m` (i.e. the length and all the elements are known in advance).

Is there a possibility to join the workers as the pool is still executing, **provided that** there less remaining tasks than active workers? Or, more generally, how can we achieve such behaviour (i.e. without necessarily a Pool)?

For instance, given `n` processes and `m` tasks, with `m >= n`, there will be a point in the execution when `n == m`, so, from this point onward, each process finishing a task will be joined.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a tiny bit confused. Are you trying to join all the workers in a pool when there is less tasks than workers or only join the ones that are done?

Comment: Join the processes that finished the work. For instance, if there are 5 tasks and 5 processes, the first process to finish a task will be joined; and it is safe to do so, since there will be 4 tasks and 4 processes, and so on.

Comment: This is some use-case I came across. Maybe there are some low-level details / concerns that may not be immediately obvious.

Comment: Were you trying to tackle memory leakage or high mem usage in the idle workers? `Pool` can take `maxtasksperchild` which restarts worker process once the worker has finished this number of tasks. This was originally used for avoiding memory use piling up during the execution of a worker process. When set to 1, this could kill the idle worker, but I'm not sure. Depending on your *real* use case, this could be helpful even if it does not kill idle worker.

Answer (score 0):

Were you trying to reduce memory leakage or high memory usage in the idle workers?

`Pool` can take `maxtasksperchild` which restarts worker process once the worker has finished this number of tasks. This was originally used for avoiding memory usage piling up during the execution of a worker process. When set to 1, this may kill the idle worker, but I'm not sure. Depending on your *real* use case, this could be helpful even if it does not kill idle worker.